# How to change hover info to display text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm currently working with a scatterplot in ggplot2 and I wanted to change the label to read text and then the value rather than the raw value on the label. How would I do that here?
Here's my scatterplot's code:

```
scatter_summary <- midwest %>%
      filter(state == input$state)

        scatter <- ggplot(data = scatter_summary,
         mapping = aes(x = percollege, y = percpovertyknown)) + 
    geom_point(aes(fill = input$state), shape = 21, color = "white") + 
    labs(
      x = "Percent with college education", 
      y = "Poverty rate", 
      title = "Midwest Data",
      subtitle = "States with higher college education rates tend to have lower poverty rates") + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
    scale_size(range = c(0, 12)) +
    guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(col = "black"), text = paste0("State: ", input$state)), 
           fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5))) +
    theme_bw()
```

Comment: Could you please use `dput(scatter_summary)`, edit your question and paste the output in order to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I used ```dput(scatter_summary)``` instead of ```data = scatter_summary```. Is that what you were talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I was asking you to add your data to the question in order to help you!

Comment: Ohhh I'm not sure how to do that, but I put in the whole scatter_summary function. The dataframe I'm using is one pre-loaded with dplyr.

Comment: Type `dput(scatter_summary)` on your console, copy the output, edit the question, paste that output and format it as code. Then, we can help!

Comment: Ohh. It's saying that scatter_summary isn't found, even though it's literally right above it.

Comment: The code doesn't work directly because you pasted from your shiny code, but `input$state` does not exist.  Also, currently, your `filter( ... == ..)` is only selecting a single value.  Thus, there is no need for a guide.  You should put the filtered value into the title.  If you want many values, you should use `filter( ... %in% ...)`.  Also, I understand switching IL with Illinois.  But it seems like you want to replace IL with State: IL.  You probably want to use `labs(fill = "State:")` instead.